# Google Web App - Search box to filter the data from Google Spread sheet

Tags: html, google-sheets, web-applications

Thanks in advance. Just to start with, I am not a coder, but I keep on researching. I made a search Web App to filter the data from Google spreadsheet which has more than 2000+ rows, which keeps on increasing day by day and around 135 columns for different Institutes. So, it was messy to search in that Google sheet, and hence I created this web app.

Everything is working smoothly until the records were around 1200 rows but now I am facing an issue to display more than 2000 records. The Web App Search box displays the list based on the key we pressed. Like if we enter "A", it will display the names starting from the alphabet "A". So, what I do is, I keep on adding the new tags (Institute names) and it works well but now suddenly after adding few records, it says unable to open the file.

Request you to please look into this and let me know any alternative or correct this code to work smoothly regardless of the numbers of tags or rows. Thank you so much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>      
        <base target="_top">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- <link href="path/to/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="path/to/select2.min.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script> -->

         <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Autocomplete using Jquery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.
css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $( function() {
    var searchtext = [
"Australian Catholic University",
"Australian National University (ANU)",
"Central Queensland University",
"Royal Melbourne Institute of Technology (RMIT)",
/*Like this we have more that 2000 names of Institutes*/
  
    ];
    $( "#searchtext" ).autocomplete({
      source: searchtext
  
/* #the tags is the id of the input element
source: tags is the list of available tags*/
  
  
    });
  } );
            //PREVENT FORMS FROM SUBMITTING / PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR
          function preventFormSubmit() {
            var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
              forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              });
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit, true);

          // $(document).ready(function() {
          // $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
          // });              

          function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById("searchtext").size = "70";
          }

          //HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
          function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
           // document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
          }

        
          //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
          function createTable(dataArray) {
            if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){
              var result = "<table class='table table-sm table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                           "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                             "<tr>"+                               //Table headings 
                              "<th scope='col'>Institution</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Agreement with</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Type of institution</th>"+                              
                              "<th scope='col'>Country</th>"+

                              /*Around 100+ Columns are there*/

                          "</thead>";
              for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
                  result += "<tr>";
                  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
                      result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
                  }
                  result += "</tr>";
              }
              result += "</table>";
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              div.innerHTML = result;
            }else{
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              //div.empty()
              div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
            }
          }        

        </script>
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ~ END ---------------------------------------------------- -->
              </head>
    <body style="background-color:#cdffcd;">
      <h1 align="center"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=16SqA92JMCD3AVWH07BeyPPLlEBaO_4Ae" alt="logo" width="120" height="100"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;The SoT Search Form</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ------------------------------------------------ -->
 <form id="search-form" class="form-inline" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)" action="/action_page.php" method="get">                  
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                      <label for="searchtext" align="center"><strong>Search for the provider</strong></label>
  
</div>
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">  
        <input id="searchtext" name="searchtext" class="form-control" onclick="myFunction()" placeholder="Enter the name.." align="center">
                      
<!-- On keyup calls the function everytime a key is released -->

                     </div>
                     
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Search</button>
                    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" id="resetbutton" style='margin-left:16px' value="Reset">
                  </form>
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ~ END ------------------------------------------- -->
              
              </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ------------------------------------------------ -->
                <div id="search-results" class="table-responsive">
                  <!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->
                </div>
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

============= Code File===========================================

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}


/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  var result = "";
  if(formObject.searchtext){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(formObject.searchtext);
  }
  return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = 'xxxxxxx'; 
  var dataRage        = 'ABC!A2:DV1500';                                    
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRage).values;
  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

Comment: Can you  provide the exact error message and indicate where it occurs? Is the error ocurring client-side or server-side?

Comment: It says - Sorry, unable to open the file at present.

Please check the address and try again.

Get stuff done with Google Drive

Apps in Google Drive make it easy to create, store and share online documents, spreadsheets, presentations and more.

Learn more at drive.google.com/start/apps.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any other way to display or auto-populate list based on the key pressed. As I have more than 2000+ Institutes names which will keep on adding in the sheet and I want the search to be done based on those Names. Previously the code was working perfectly fine as I kept on adding new names in the list, but today when I am trying to add around 100 new names in the list, it is showing the error.

Comment: Is this message being shown in the browser when you open the WebApp? Are you signed in with mutiple accounts simultanously?

Comment: Yes, this message shows in the browser once I open the WebApp. No, I am not signed in with multiple accounts. The thing is it is still working fine, this error shows when I am adding some more tags. So, I believe that there must be some limit to add list names. I would really appreciate it if you can fix this.

Comment: CAn you see any errors in your execution logs?

Comment: No error in the execution log, everything is perfectly okay.

Comment: I have figured out that there is an issue while adding more names (tags) in the HTML code of the Index file otherwise it is working fine. So, is there any way to include a list option that could have more than 2000+ entries? It seems there are some restrictions which does not allow after certain amount of tags to be displayed.

Comment: Can somebody please help me with this?? Just want to know a way to display more than 2000+ (& will keep on increasing) Names in a List that only appears on a key press.

Comment: Hi, Can someone help with Select2 box coding that we can use to display a huge list? I mean which part I have to replace and how to include Select2 instead.